# Tough second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, partial-derivative, mathematical-physics

I can't figure out this diff equation (in cylindrical coordinate). How can I solve it ?
Any comments appreciated

$$ 
\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dE}{dr})+\frac{d^2E}{dz^2}+(\epsilon_0 k_0^2-\frac{1}{r^2}k_x^2R^2)E=\epsilon k_0^2E_0
$$

$$
r_1<r<r_2 ;0<z<d   
$$
 $(r_1, r_2, d \in \Bbb R )$
$$E(r,0)=0; E(r,d)=0$$
$$E(r_1,z)=0; E(r_2,z)=0 $$

Comment: While you have prescribed boundary conditions along the planes $z=0$ and $z=d$, you haven't done so at $r=r_1$ and $r_2$. Without this, it's unlikely that your diff eq will have a unique solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If we set the other boundary condition for r as ; $$ E(r_1,z)=0; E(r_2,z)=0 $$. What the E would be ?

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head. But that amendment should be in your question, rather than just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the boundary conditions, the PDE and the inhomogeneous term doesn't depend on $z$.

To construct an ansatz which satisfy the boundary conditions at $z = 0$ and $d$, we 
rewrite $E$ as a sum of standing waves in the $z$-direction. More precisely,

$$E(r,z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty E_n(r) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi z}{d}\right)\tag{*1}$$

For $z \in (0,d)$, the inhomogeneous term on the RHS can be rewritten as

$$\epsilon k_0^2 E_0 = \frac{4 \epsilon k_0^2 E_0}{\pi}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\frac{\sin\left((2\ell+1)\frac{\pi z}{d}\right)}{2\ell+1}\tag{*2}$$
This suggests in the ansatz $(*1)$, we only need to keep the terms for odd $n$.
From now on, we will assume $n = 2\ell + 1$ is an odd positive integer.

Throw $(*1)$ and $(*2)$ into the PDE, we obtain following ODE for $E_n(r)$

$$\left( r^2\frac{d^2}{dr^2} + r\frac{d}{dr} + \left( \epsilon_0 k_0^2 - \frac{n^2\pi^2}{d^2}\right) r^2 - k_x^2 R^2 \right) E_n(r) = \frac{4\epsilon k_0^2 E_0}{\pi n} r^2$$

When $\displaystyle\;n < \sqrt{\epsilon_0} \frac{k_0 d}{\pi}\;$, introduce variables $x, \nu$ and function $\phi_n(x)$:

$$x = r \sqrt{\epsilon_0 k_0^2 - \frac{n^2\pi^2}{d^2}},\quad
\nu = k_x R,\quad\text{ and }\quad
E_n(r) = \frac{4\epsilon k_0^2 E_0}{\pi n\left( \epsilon_0 k_0^2 - \frac{n^2\pi^2}{d^2}\right)} \phi_n(x)$$

we reduce the ODE for $E_n$ to an inhomogeneous 
[Bessel equation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bessel_equation) in $\phi_n(x)$.

$$\left( x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + x\frac{d}{dx} + (x^2 - \nu^2)\right) \phi_n(x) = x^2$$

Its general solution has the form

$$\phi_n(x) = A J_\nu(x) + B Y_\nu(x) + 
\frac{\pi}{2}\left(
Y_\nu(x)\int x J_\nu(x) dx - J_\nu(x)\int x Y_\nu(x) dx
\right)$$

where $A, B$ are constants to be determined. You can use your boundary condition at $r = r_1$ and $r_2$ to pin down $A$ and $B$.

When $\displaystyle\;n > \sqrt{\epsilon_0} \frac{k_0 d}{\pi}\;$,
the coefficient in the $r \to x$ change of variable  becomes imaginary,
one need to replace above expression by corresponding modified Bessel functions.

Comment: integrate with respect to $x$ and then replace $x$ by $r\sqrt{\cdot}$ in the result.

Comment: One more thing, with the solution we have just odd modes (n),but how can calculate both even and odd modes ? Thanks

Comment: There is no even $n$ part in the particular solution. When $n$ is even, the corresponding function will be "odd" with respect to the reflection along the plane $z = \frac{d}{2}$.

Comment: When $n$ is even, $\sin\frac{n\pi z}{d} = -\sin\frac{n\pi(d-z)}{d}$. The general solution can have even $n$ part but they are just ordinary/modified Bessel functions and they won't be there unless the whole thing is on resonance.

Comment: Hi achille, if $ E_0 $ also depends on r and z "$E_0(r,z)$" the solution will change ?

Comment: If $E_0$ depends on $r$ and $z$, the solution will definite change. However, the methodology is the same. You break $E_0(r,z)$ as a sum of function $\sum_n f(r)\sin\frac{n\pi z}{d}$. For each mode, you again get an inhomogeneous Bessel equation. You need to put something different into the integration part of the particular solution. There is a formula of what that should be in the link in the answer.